# Horizontal scale of celery workers results in same processing time

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, celery, samba

We are experiencing an unexpected behaviour with celery when we scale horizontally with celery (increasing the number of our instances).

The current processing time for our tasks it takes is just over 1 hour, this is same time when we increase our worker instances if we scale to 16x worker1 and 16x worker2 or have 4x worker1 and 4x worker2.

After scraping metrics into prometheus / grafana we can see that disk read,write and network to the samba is not the bottle neck also the cpu and ram on the workers and brokers are not maxing out we are also seeing that the tasks are completing in batches and waiting for the batch of tasks to complete before starting the next rather than continuously, this causes a brief pause before the processing starts again.

My question would be is this expected behaviour of celery? where I would expect my total processing time to decrease as I horizontal scale out.

Our setup:

```
Rabbitmq Broker 3.6.14 8GB RAM 2CPU  
Celery 4.1.0 (apmq)  
Python application  
2 queues  
8x worker1 8GB RAM 2CPU  
8x worker2 8GB RAM 2CPU  
all in docker containers  
writing to samba share
```

celery configuration: `worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1`

run command:

- worker1: `celery -A node_slave worker -n worker@%h --loglevel=debug --concurrency=2`
- worker2: `celery -A node_slave worker -n worker@%h --loglevel=debug --concurrency=2 -Q queue2`
- configurations tested: gevent, Ofair
- background of processing: messages are sent to a central queue for example queue1,

worker1 
will go and retrieve messages from queue1 and run the application which retrieves a file from a directory on the samba share (input) and convert the file to a specific file type and puts it to (output) on the samba share
worker1 will also write a message into queue2 asynchronously

worker2
runs application against files in queue2 and writes to nosql backend.

Comment: Right now your question is completely unclear. I tried to help with formatting but I'm really not sure what is your question about. Try to phrase it in the simplest way possible. Its a good idea to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the formatting I will take a look at the the link you have provided and revise my question

Answer (score 0):

Although general purpose SSD Disk on EC2 has a burstable IOPS this was our issue

increasing the IOPS on the samba instance and moving to provisioned IOPS and also increasing the instance size provided us with better throughput